# What is the difference between $man and man on a mac

Tags: macos, man

On a terminal, the commands `$man` and `man` seem to do slightly different things.

For example `$man open` vs. `man open`. It looks like `$man` is the same as `man` except it prints the output directly instead of opening it in vim.

Is there something universal about a `$` prefix? Is there some other difference between the two programs?

Below is the output when using `type`

```
~
$ type $man
~
$ type man
man is hashed (/usr/bin/man)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`man` is an external command that displays manual page for a given argument. Thus `man open` displays a manual page for `open` command.

---

`$man` is a variable which value you can check using `echo $man`.

If the value of `$man` is empty then executing `$man open` is the same as executing `open`.

`/usr/bin/open` command executed without arguments displays simple help.

Comment: Oh I see, I happened to catch myself in a potentially confusing scenario. Thanks for clarifying.